# How to take out elements knowing their indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I just have a little trouble with my program, I want to take a few elements of a list knowing their indexes and then add this elements to another list... For example:

```
a= ['dog','cat','house','car']
c=[]
#list with the indexes:
b=[0,2]
```

so I wanto to take out the elements of a with the indexes "0" and "2" and add them to the c list.

Comment: `c=[a[i] for i in b]`

Comment: these information (    `del list1[2];`, `list1.append('a')`    ) may help you ,you can google it by yourself for the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your indices array, pop the item at the index and append it to your new array.

```
i = 0
while i < len(b):
c.append(a.pop(b[i]))
i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

The comments were helpful too, but here it is concisely:
Loop through elements in b, take out index from a and append it to c.

```
for i in b:
    c.append(a.pop(i))
```

There might be a way to do it with list comprehension, but I don't know that yet.
Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to use list comprehensions: `c = [a.pop(i) for i in b]`

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks for the info! I'm still learning, but I guessed it might be something of the sort.

Comment: You're very welcome! You can include that in your answer if you want, although it's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an element from a list:

```
a.remove(0)
```

Or you can do

```
del a[0]
```

To add an element into a list:

```
c.insert(0,'dog')
c.insert(1,'house')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the first array into a numpy array. Then you can simply pass on the indices from b.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['dog','cat','house','car'])
b = [0,2]
c = a[b]

print(c) 
>>> array(['dog', 'house'],
  dtype='<U5')
```

to convert c back into a list, simply use .tolist()

```
print(c.tolist())
>>> ['dog', 'house']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this little code :

```
a= ['dog','cat','house','car']
b=[0,2]

print(list(map(lambda x:a[x],b)))
```

output:

```
['dog', 'house']
```